# Is it necessary to be a resident in Italy to use the health system for free?

Tags: health-insurance, italy, health-system

I've moved abroad. Can I still use the health system for free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to use another country's healthcare **for free** will depend on a few things.

Firstly, whether or not they will just willingly treat.  The UK is pretty good for this, for example in some situations.

Secondly, it'll come down to reciprocity.  Some countries have agreements that they'll treat the citizens of each other's country if visiting.  For example - New Zealand and Australia.

Thirdly, some countries will treat you IF you're a resident, working there or studying there.

In [Italy, Healthcare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healthcare_in_Italy) for everyone is free for **emergencies** - they won't turn you away.  If it turns out not to be an emergency, you may be required to pay 50 Euro at the hospital.

If you move there with a Permit of Stay, you'll be treated under the [Servizio Sanitario Nazionale](http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/salute/p1_3.jsp?tema=Tu_e_il_Servizio_Sanitario_Nazionale) (National Health System) like any Italian.

If you're seeing a specialist or having blood tests, x-rays or similar, you may have to pay a small fee as well.

Comment: Note that the "small fee" applies in any case (even for residents and nationals).

Comment: The National Health System in reality is more a Regional Health System: the kind of medical procedure, the time that you need to wait for having it and the amount of the "small fee" (called "ticket") change on regional basis.